# usage of "X serves to Y"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-patterns, active-voice

I just saw a paragraph that started with this sentence:

"This article serves to discuss native advertising with software engineers."

What is the justification for using "serves to" instead of just writing:

"This article discusses native advertising..."

Are there any cases in which X "serves to" Y cannot (or should not) be replaced by the active version of the verb Y?

Comment: Just another way of saying "the purpose of this article is to discuss..." - merely personal writing style, I'd say.

Comment: Yes, that is a similar way to say it. I guess what I'm asking is *why* would one want to say that, instead of just using the active verb?

Comment: "Discusses" and "serves" are both active verbs. "Serves to discuss" is a "[catenative construction](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-catenative-verb-1689832)" where a verb is followed by a non-finite form of another verb. I would recommend avoiding using the term "active" in this question as it is usually reserved in grammatical discussions for referring to the difference between constructions like "X sees Y" (active) and "Y is seen (by X)" (passive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To serve to + verb*, meaning "to serve the purpose of *verb + ing*," is often pointless filler, especially in academic writing, that should be the ready victim of judicious editing. It seems less obnoxious, even necessary, however, when the purpose itself is topical:

> The inner polymer sheath [of a pipeline] is designed to serve as a leak-proof fluid conduit, whereas the outer sheath *[serves to keep](https://books.google.de/books?id=pBt9SXzAFJYC&pg=PA69&dq=%22serves%20to%20keep%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHopzt_7fZAhWP2aQKHZb2A9E4KBDoAQgbMAA)* the reinforcement steel together while protecting the inner structure from abrasion.

Though they could be omitted, the parallel instances of *to serve* make the comparison of purpose much clearer to the reader.

Here, too, the purpose of something is topical:

> A trade mark is a sign that [serves to distinguish](https://books.google.de/books?id=7vqPBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA58&dq=%22serves%20to%20distinguish%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRrsrJ9LfZAhWOCOwKHWE5AcM4FBDoAQhOMAg) the goods of a company... From this definition it follows that a trade mark only has value if it is actually used to this end.

The  construction also has some value when an action is undertaken for a particular purpose but has unintended or unforeseen consequences, usually modified by *only*:

> The practice of flooding flowerbeds [as a watering method] only [serves to keep](https://books.google.de/books?id=1f4rVyk6O20C&pg=PA45&dq=%22serves%20to%20keep%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4k5fB-rfZAhWJhqYKHQq1Drw4FBDoAQg1MAQ) the soil beneath the adjacent foundation wetter than it needs to be and induces excessive heave beneath the foundation.

The construction is also used as a hedge in process statements:

> The second part [serves to clarify](https://books.google.de/books?id=1QFSk3D1QU8C&pg=PA75&dq=%22serves%20to%20clarify%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivx86BhrjZAhWSjqQKHaX2Cfo4FBDoAQhMMAg) the concept of federalism by distinguishing between federations and centralized states, on the one hand, and federations and confederations, on the other.

It is highly unlikely that the concept of federalism will, for all time, be clarified by what this author is about to tell you. And while I personally despise all process statements like these — don't tell me that you're about to tell me something, just tell me! — at least don't set a goal you won't be able to reach.

This is why academic writing is riddled with *serves to show, demonstrate, illustrate, prove, etc.* since these actions are by their nature rarely completely realized.